# How can I declare 2-dimentional array as parameter in function In MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I have a function that gets a matrix and do some operations on it.
but I do not know how to declare function's parameter .
this is my function Code:

```
function D=Shirinkage(a)
    D(1,:)=a(1,:);%this is X1
    for i=2:4
        D(i,4)=0;
        for j=1:3
            D(i,j)=1/2*(a(1,j)+a(i,j));
            D(i,4)=D(i,j)^2 + D(i,4); %object function
        end
     end
end
```

I tried `a(4,4)` instead of `a` (parameter of the function),but  the error does not appear.
Error:

```
??? Input argument "a" is undefined.

Error in ==> Shirinkage at 3
    D(1,:)=a(1,:);%this is X1
```

also I want to declare `D` correctly.

appreciating any help.

Edited:
 i call my function from a script file , in this way:
I have a 2-dimention array(matrix) its size is : 4*4 and its name is A.
i want my function gets this matrix and do the operation on it and the result can be saved again in it.

```
A=Shirinkage(A)
```

e.x. A has this values:

```
A=[1,2,3,4;2,3,4,5;5,6,7,8;1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Hi, how are you making the function call? You are supposed to create a 2d array `a` first and then call the function `Shrinkage(a)` for this to work

Comment: @nahomyaja I added it, can u check it again?

Comment: @sama : I created a matrix z=magic(4); it creates a 4x4 matrix. I called your function and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you created is working fine. The only recommendation I have to pre-allocate the size of `D` as it varies in each iteration in your current code.

```
function D = Shirinkage(a)
    D = zeros(size(a));
    D(1,:) = a(1,:);                        %this is X1
    for i = 2:4
        D(i,4) = 0;
        for j = 1:3
            D(i,j) = 0.5*(a(1,j) + a(i,j));
            D(i,4) = D(i,4) + D(i,j)^2;     %object function
        end
     end
end
```

The function was called from command window by using the same matrix you have used and it gave the following output.

[image: Output]

The error you have posted says that the function hasn't received the argument `a`. If your script and the function are in the same MATLAB path, this should work perfectly.